# Node actions apply to only 1 node

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I just installed a 3 node cassandra (2.0.11) community cluster with a single seed node. I installed opscenter (5.0.2) on the seed node and everything is working fairly well. The only issue I am having is that any node actions I perform (stop, start, compact, etc) apply only to the seed node. Even if I choose a different node on the ring or list, the action always happens on the seed node.

I watched the opscenter logs and can see requests for /ops/compact/ip_address and the ip address is the correct node that I chose but the action always run on the seed instance.

All agents have been installed on all the nodes and the cluster is fully operational. I can run nodetool compact on each node and see the compaction progress in opscenter.

I have each node configured to listen on an internal address and have verified that the rpc server is open on the network. I have also tried adding the cluster using a non-seed node but all actions continue to run on the seed node.

Answer (score 2):

Posted the answer above but I'll explain more in detail for anyone else with this issue.

I changed rpc_address and listen_address in cassandra.yaml in order to listen on a private ip address. I restarted cassandra and the cluster could communicate easily. The datastax-agent was still reporting 127.0.0.1 to opscenter as the rpc address. I found this out by enabling trace logging in opscenter.

If you modify anything in cassandra.yaml, make sure you restart the datastax-agent as it apparently caches the data.

Comment: Fyi I've filed an internal ticket (OPSC-4194) to detect when c* is restarted and break any caches that should be updated as a result.  Thanks for the detailed info here.